# VBA my array doesn't paste the values right on the sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that fills in different values in the tool and puts the answers in an array. The array fills good and the values in the array are correct. But when i paste the values from the array to the sheet, not all values are correct. Here is my code and a picture of the output. The first 6 rows are how it's supposed to be.

```
Range("F34").Value = 15
Range("F37").Value = 0.5
Range("H56").Value = "Recirculation"

Dim c As LongLong, t As LongLong, m As LongLong
Dim p As String, e As LongLong
Dim MyArray() As String
Dim x As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ReDim MyArray(545, 5)
    For c = 5000 To 50000 Step 5000
        For t = 40 To 70 Step 5
            For m = 3 To 8 Step 1
                
                Range("F33").Value2 = c
                Range("F35").Value2 = t
                Range("F36").Value2 = m
                e = Range("L30").Value2
                Range("F214").Value = ""
                Range("F215").Value = ""
                If IsError(Sheets("8. Financial").Range("M87").Value2) Then
                    Get_Fan
                    If IsError(Range("P47").Value2) Then
                        p = "A"
                    Else
                        p = Sheets("8. Financial").Range("M87").Value
                    End If
                Else
                    p = Sheets("8. Financial").Range("M87").Value
                End If
            
                MyArray(x, 0) = c & t & m
                MyArray(x, 1) = c
                MyArray(x, 2) = t
                MyArray(x, 3) = m
                MyArray(x, 4) = p
                MyArray(x, 5) = e
                x = x + 1

            Next m
        Next t
    Next c

x = 420

    For c = 60000 To 80000 Step 10000
        For t = 40 To 70 Step 5
            For m = 3 To 8 Step 1
                
                Range("F33").Value2 = c
                Range("F35").Value2 = t
                Range("F36").Value2 = m
                e = Range("L30").Value2
                Range("F214").Value = ""
                Range("F215").Value = ""
                If IsError(Sheets("8. Financial").Range("M87").Value2) Then
                    Get_Fan
                    If IsError(Range("P47").Value2) Then
                        p = "A"
                    Else
                        p = Sheets("8. Financial").Range("M87").Value
                    End If
                Else
                    p = Sheets("8. Financial").Range("M87").Value
                End If
            
                MyArray(x, 0) = c & t & m
                MyArray(x, 1) = c
                MyArray(x, 2) = t
                MyArray(x, 3) = m
                MyArray(x, 4) = p
                MyArray(x, 5) = e
                x = x + 1

            Next m
        Next t
    Next c

Worksheets("Light table").Range("A2:F547").Value2 = MyArray
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the formatting on the cells? If the first few rows have a different formatting (number, currency, text) than the rows below that can cause inconsistency.

Comment: The formating is set to standard.

Comment: Could you try Worksheets("Light table").Range("A2:F547").Clear before Worksheets("Light table").Range("A2:F547").Value2 = MyArray? Just to isolate formatting issues...

Comment: The clear before was definitely a good idea thanks. I also changed the code for pasting the array to the worksheet and it seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

I used a different method to put the array on the worksheet and this seems to be working.

Worksheets("Light table").Range("A2:F600").Clear
Dim Destination As Range
Set Destination = Worksheets("Light table").Range("A2")
Destination.Resize(UBound(MyArray, 1), UBound(MyArray, 2)).Value2 = MyArray